# go back to previus div

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following ajax code to show me a php page in div (i think.. if for example i have a link like this: `<a href="#" onClick="show_manage_team()" >back</a>` if i send value = "" show me the first page in div.. how i can do that? )

```
function show_manage_team(str)
{


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {


  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {


    document.getElementById("item2_section5").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

}
xmlhttp.open("GET","manage_team_teacher2.php?id_team="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

i have firstly in the same div an other page with name manage_team_teacher.php which have the following link about going to page manage_team_teacher2.php:

```
<a href="#" onClick="show_manage_team(<?php echo $row['id_team']; ?>)" >manage</a>
```

when in div (item2_section5) appears page manage_team_teacher2.php i want to have a back button and when i click it i go again to page manage_team_teacher.php in the same div. (the url is the same and **not work** go back() function of javascript).

Comment: consider using iframes than div's this will help achive your requirement...

Comment: why you use `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject` with jquery ??? I also see no any jquery code here.

Comment: to acheive your goal with javascript you have to use [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) for crossbrowser compatibility and hash fallback

Comment: is ajax.. before i ask the question I thought that those who know jquery probably know and ajax

Comment: I set correct tags, also your question not about ajax :) but oabout history manipulating

Comment: ok ;) but i am new and i need help for coding :(

Comment: check history.js they have nice examples

Comment: i think.. if for example i have a link like this: <a href="#" onClick="show_manage_team()" >back</a> if i send value = "" show me the other page in div.. how i can do that?